# Simple way to send push notification using new GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I was searched about this , But all tutorials i found is old.

I want a simple ways to:

1. Register device using Android & Java and send registration id to my web site to save it.
2. Create page to send messages to all registration ids.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: old tutorials may still work... have you tried them? also, this is not really a question

Comment: will you please list down tutorial what you have seen?

Comment: really ? because i was saw "deprecated" in SDK Manager.

Comment: now it becomes part of google play services @MalekSa

Comment: Ok , What is the minSDKVersion for play services ?

Comment: Registering with the GCM server for the newer API  is all covered here : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html. Saving the regId on your own website is up to you depending on what web server you have implemented

Comment: any device which has google play service will surely works.In general, devices running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or later and have the Google Play Store app installed as per the documentation. https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html?hl=en-IN

Comment: More details of what have you done so far are necessary to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see this and follow it.

Hope this might helps you

http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/